# $_ outputting extra bit of data

Tags: perl, network-programming, client-server

The static $_ might needs to be flushed. It is tried to be done by $|=1;.

[image]

***DESIRED OUTPUT:***

*CLIENT*

```
Connected to the Server.
sent to server : SAS4
sent to server : 50
sent to server : SAS_ACTION LOGIN
sent to server : LOGIN bss
sent to server : PASSWORD cleint
sent to server : $END$
Message received from Server : SAS4
Message received from Server : 61
Message received from Server : SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
Message received from Server : ACK_STATUS 0
Message received from Server : ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
Message received from Server : $END$
```

*SERVER*

```
Waiting for the Client.
Connected from : 127.0.0.1, Port : 1862
Message received from Client : SAS4
Message received from Client : 50
Message received from Client : SAS_ACTION LOGIN
Message received from Client : LOGIN bss
Message received from Client : PASSWORD cleint
Message received from Client : $END$
server to client : SAS4
server to client : 61
server to client : SAS_ACTION LOGIN_ACK
server to client : ACK_STATUS 0
server to client : ACK_MESSAGE Logged In
server to client : $END$
```

***CODE :***

**CLIENT**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (PeerHost => '127.0.0.1', PeerPort => '1055', Proto    => 'tcp', Reuse    => 1) or die "$!\n";

print "Connected to the Server.\n";

send_login();
$|=1;
receive_loginack();
$socket->close();

sub send_login
{
    my $login_txt = "Login.txt";
    open LOGIN, '<', $login_txt or die "Cannot open $login_txt $!\n";
    my @login = <LOGIN>;
    close LOGIN;

    my $logfile = "logfile.txt";
    open LOG, '>>', $logfile or die "Cannot open $logfile ($!)\n";

    foreach my $login (@login)
    {
        print $socket $login;
        print LOG "CLIENT : $login";
        print "sent to server : $login";
        #last if ($login eq "\$END\$\n");

    }
    close LOG;
}

sub receive_loginack
{
    while (<$socket>)
    {   
        print"Message received from Server : $_";
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (LocalHost => '127.0.0.1', LocalPort => '1055', Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 1, Reuse => 1) or die "Oops: $! \n";

print "Waiting for the Client.\n";
server_loop();
$socket->close();

sub server_loop
{
OUTER:
    while (my $clientsocket = $socket->accept())
    {
        print "connected from : ", $clientsocket->peerhost();
        print ", port : ", $clientsocket->peerport(), "\n";

INNER:
        while (<$clientsocket>)                                 #
        {                                                       #
            print"Message received from Client : $_";           #
            last INNER if ($_ eq "\$END\$\n");                  #       RECEIVING
            #last OUTER if ($_ eq "\$QUIT\$\n");                #
            print $clientsocket $_;                             #
        }                                                       #

        my $login_ack = "login_ack.txt";
        open LOGINACK, '<', $login_ack or die "Cannot open login acknowledgment file $login_ack ($!)\n";
        my @loginack = <LOGINACK>;
        close LOGINACK;

        my $logfile = "logfile.txt";
        open LOG, ">>", $logfile or die "cannot open $logfile ($!)\n";

        foreach my $loginack (@loginack)
        {
            $|=1;
            print $clientsocket $loginack;
            print LOG "SERVER : $loginack";
            print "server to client : $loginack";
            #last if ($loginack eq "\$END\$\n");
        }

        close LOG;
        close $clientsocket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server's input loop contains:

```
print $clientsocket $_;
```

So everything the client sends to the server is being sent back to the client, before the login_ack.txt file. So the client prints it as a message received from the server.

Comment: Thank you for looking into the matter. Coming to the ans, when I comment out the sending part in Server(foreach loop),
the client still prints that particular part.
My take on the same was that it is being received from the Client's end itself.

Comment: No, there's nothing that would automatically cause the client to read back what it sent. Flushing has nothing to do with it, the two directions of a stream are independent.

Comment: ohh. so how shall the situation be dealt?

Comment: Check again that you really removed that `print` statement. Are you sure you restarted the server when you did that? I simply don't believe that you're still having the problem with that statement removed, it's obviously the cause.